# routing/url mapping broken for link_to tag in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, url-mapping

Ive been trying to get this to work for 3 days now. I cant seem to understand why it doesn work. When the user clicks that link_to tag on the view it should execute the csv function in the controller. Instread I get an exception.

---

Here are the relevant files

Controller file: (users_controller.rb)

```
def csv 

end
```

(Routes.rb):

```
resources :users
```

View: (show.html.erb)

```
 <%= link_to 'Click HERE to open file', @user.image.url  %><br/><br/><br/>
 <%= label_tag(:q, "Parse CSV File:") %><br/>
 <%= link_to 'CSV', csv_user_path %>
 <% end %>
```

When I click on the "link_to 'CSV'.. tag above. It gives me this exception:

```
 NameError in Users#show 
 Showing /Users/AM/Documents/RailsWS/bmc_mam/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #47 raised:
Extracted source (around line #47):

44:         
45:  <%= label_tag(:q, "Parse CSV File:") %><br/>
46:  
47: <%= link_to 'CSV', csv_user_path %>
48:             
49:         
50:
```

The browser URL is as follows when the exception occurs:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/28
```

Its clearly getting to the function but the URL mapping /routing is clearly messed up. I m wondering how to fix it.....Ive tried several approaches over the past few days, none seem to be working. 
This is the closest Ive gotten to making it work as in ...

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

After post answer posted below by @Gavin Miller:

I cahnged my routes.rb file to this:

```
get 'csv' => 'users#csv'
resources :users
```

Now Im getting this exception:

```
NameError in Users#show

Showing /Users/AM/Documents/RailsWS/bmc_mam/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #47    raised:

undefined local variable or method `csv_user_path' for #<#  <Class:0x00000104e7f6f8>:0x00000103a23c68>

Extracted source (around line #47):

44:         
45:             <%= label_tag(:q, "Parse CSV File:") %><br/>
46:             
47:             <%= link_to 'CSV', csv_user_path %>
48:             
49:         
50:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declaring `resources :users` is only going to infer the 7 standard RESTful actions<sup>1</sup>. if you want `csv` to be accepted as a route, you'll have to explicitly define it:

```
get 'csv' => 'controller#action'
```

where `controller == users` and `action == csv`.

---

Re-addressing the edited question... You'll need to pass a user object to the `csv_user_path` function:

```
<%= link_to 'CSV', csv_user_path(@user) %>
```

---

It also appears like you'd like the url to be associated with the user, so you can declare it as a `member` to get a url like: `http://localhost:3000/users/28/csv` for that result you can use this code:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'csv'
  end
end
```

---

<sup>1</sup> RESTful actions are `index, new, create, show, edit, update, destroy` as seen in [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

Comment: Awesome man. THAT WORKED!!!!!! THANKS SO MUCH!!
Ive been going crazy for the last 2 days!!

Comment: @banditKing totally know the feeling. You can also run `rake routes` to see the urls that are being generated for you automatically from your routes. The left most column will give you a list of functions that you can add `_url` or `_path` to the end of to generate urls.

Comment: in your case you'll see that there's a value in the left hand column called `csv_user`

Comment: thanks. thats encouraging. i was ready to abandon rails for something ele not anymmore ;)